# Visual Studio 2019 Slow Startup

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2019, startup

In the last month or so, my VS2019 startup has been getting slower and slower. Opening a mind-sized solution (~50 projects) used to take a couple of minutes, now it's taking >15 minutes. Is there a way I can get "behind the scenes" and see what it's doing that's causing the slowness?

Comment: I suspect some run-away database; try to delete `.vs` folder in your solution directory. You may want to save it to analyze later if that helps.

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein Thank you very much! Deleting the .vs folder did help.

Comment: I sure don't mind. But when I clicked the up arrow to mark the answer, I was told since I'm new, < 15 posts, my vote won't be displayed :-(

Comment: Just gonna add this as a comment. I had a degrade in VS 2022 launching time. Turned out that the Windows update, specifically, Cumulative Update Preview for .NET Framework 3.5, 4.8 and 4.8.1 was the reason for this. How I fixed is simply ran this script from MS https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/main/tools/DrainNGENQueue/DrainNGenQueue.wsf. Unfortunately, we have to run it each time .NET Framework updates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, Visual Studio has problem with some browsing databases growing out of control. There was an infamous `*.ncb` file (Non-Compile Browser?) in VS 6, that periodically needed to be deleted. People wrote plug-ins and macros to "nuke" that file and seamless reload a workspace. Apparently, some issues were preserved for over 20 years.

Modern versions of Visual Studio keep those databases in the hidden `.vs` folder in your solution directory. You can simply delete this folder, it will be re-created as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio & SSMS / SQL Server Microsoft Studio slow load time *FIX*

Disable Fusion Logging:
Press Win + R to open the Run dialog.
Type regedit and press Enter to open the Windows Registry Editor.
Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion
On the right pane, set the LogFailures DWORD value to 0 to disable logging.
Optionally, also set ForceLog DWORD value to 0 to further ensure logging is disabled.
Close the Registry Editor.
Clean Up Existing Logs (if desired):
Navigate to C:\FusionLog\ in File Explorer.
You can safely delete logs in this directory to reclaim disk space if needed.
Restart SSMS and observe the behavior in Process Monitor again. The flood of Fusion Log writes should no longer be present.

This changed my start time from 3  to 5 minutes to 5 seconds for both applications.